# Why do my sprites stutter when I move them too quickly?

Tags: java

**The Problem** 
I have some sprites animating across my screen (some spaceships).
I alter their X coordinates (like -5, for animation) in my game loop.

I want the animation to happen faster, however when I alter their coordinates too much (like position-=5 each time), the animation becomes jumpy and stutters.

For example, decrementing objects xPosition by 1 = slow moving smooth animation 
But, decrementing objects xPosition by 5 = faster, but choppy/stuttering animation

**What I've tried** 
The only way I can think is to make my game FPS like 100 with a lower position incrementing speed, which is extremely wasteful.

My game loop is below. 
(I know this isn't a great game loop, but its one of the few I understand. I also can't see how it would be a problem for this example)

```
private final int FPS = 60;
private final long TICKS = 1000/FPS; //16.67ms per update max

public void run() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(gameRunning){

        cycleEnemies();
        repaint();

        startTime += TICKS;

        sleepTime = startTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

        //So timeout isnt negative
        if(sleepTime > 0){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }else{
            //We're running behind!
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my cycle method:

```
    private void cycleEnemies(){
        for(Enemy e : enemyShips){
            e.setXPosition(e.getXPosition() - 5);
        }
    }
```

This is my drawing code:

```
private void drawEnemy(Graphics g){
    //Loop through enemyShips array, drawing all
    for(Enemy e: enemyShips){
        g.drawImage(e.getTexture().getImage(), e.getXPosition(), e.getYPosition(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome and very helpful post : http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 3):

**The problem is in your game loop**

1. You are limiting your rendering fps to your game world fps. You should update your world on a fixed timestep and either leave the render timestep to vsync or limit to something like 60..
2. You're using non floating point variable types where you should be using floating point math. This adds imprecision and can cause stutering.

Your main game loop is the most important part of your game and your implementation is less than perfect here...

A possible alternative may help you here.

```
public boolean gameRunning;
public int fps, frames;
public float delta;
public int wantedFPS = 60;

public void loop(){
    gameRunning = true;

    long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastFPS = lastTime;

    float fixedTimestep = 0;

    while(gameRunning){
        frames++;
        delta = (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime ) / 1000f;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFPS > 1000){
            fps = frames;
            frames = 0;
            lastFPS = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        //Optional loop to ensure game doesn't malfunction due to the inprecise nature of floats
        if(delta < 0.01f){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        fixedTimestep += delta;
        if(fixedTimestep >= wantedFPS/1000f){
            //perform fixed update (physics etc)
        }

        //update other game logic
        //render game
    }
}
```

*This function is untested but has the general idea of how to make a good game loop*

The optional part is there in case your system proccesses the entire game loop too quickly and `float delta` ends up as 0.